# Order two Arrays based on the same random sorting system

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My current Project is a little Jquery Game.
Every picture in the Array Bildquelle (which I saved in a json) belongs to a number in the Array numbers, but in the same order, so that Bild1 is number 1 etc.

But I want to display they in a random order. Is there a way to sort them on the same random system?

Thank you in advance!

```js
var Bildquelle = [
  "../img/Bild1.png",
  "../img/Bild2.png",
  "../img/Bild3.png",
  "../img/Bild4.png",
  "../img/Bild5.png",
  "../img/Bild6.png",
  "../img/Bild7.png",
  "../img/Bild8.png",
  "../img/Bild9.png",
  "../img/Bild10.png"
]
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
numbers.sort(function() {
  return Math.random() - .5
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var Karte = $('<img src=' + Bildquelle[i] + ' alt="Bild">').data('number', numbers[i]).attr('id', 'card' + numbers[i]).appendTo('#cardPile')
};
```

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Why have both Bildquelle and numbers? You wouldn't need numbers as the Bildquelle array is referenced by position (integer) anyways.

Comment: @JakubKeller could you you explain that to me (i am new to JS)? What would I have to change in the code?

Comment: Why don't you make `Bildquelle` and array of objects with `Id` and `Image` properties.

Comment: I got it working with the multidimensional Arrays. Thank for your help y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest is to just not use `numbers` but directly shuffle `Bildquelle` instead:

```
  Bildquelle.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  });
```

Now `Bilquelle[0]` might be `"../img/Bild9.png"` or one of the others.

If you however want to keep `Bildquelle` and `numbers` and shuffle numbers you should change `numbers` to be zero based (as arrays):

```
  var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

You could even directly get Bildquelle's keys:

```
 var numbers = Object.keys(Bildquelle);
```

Now you can shuffle that, and access the Bildquelle by a certain number:

```
  Bildquelle[ numbers[0] ]
```

or in your loop as:

```
  Bildquelle[ numbers[i] ]
```

*PS: `Bildquelle` should actually be `images` or `pictures` to follow naming conventions (and if you keep mixing languages it gets harder to read...)*