# How do I sort and shuffle javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a drag and drop card [game](https://codepen.io/shanice92/pen/pooPNOw).
I'm able to use sort and use Math.Random to shuffle:

```
answers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );
```

It works but after the cards are placed in the correct subcontainer the wrong year appears below as if it's shuffling.

Is it possible to shuffle an array by the image but still be able to sort by value(order)?

```
  var answers = [
    {
      "image":'https://www.floridamemory.com/onlineclassroom/game/cards/1822.png',
      "order":'1'
    },{
      "image":'https://www.floridamemory.com/onlineclassroom/game/cards/1839.png',
      "order":'2'
    },
    {
      "image":'https://www.floridamemory.com/onlineclassroom/game/cards/1912.png',
      "order":'3'
    }
  ];
```

Comment: What do you mean shuffle by the image?

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffle an array by the image"?

Comment: It seems like you don't need JSON objects, but just a one-dimensional array of image URLs.  And then your "order" is just the index of the image URLs.  As such, you could just shuffle the array of strings like any other array.

Comment: I'm confused about the point to this. You want to shuffle them but then also have them be ordered by the order? Either way one or the other is going to overrule the other.

Comment: Sidenote: [Don't use `.sort` and `Math.random` to shuffle arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962802/is-it-correct-to-use-javascript-array-sort-method-for-shuffling). It is not as random as you would expect.

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code? Because shuffling is normally fine - if that puts the elements in the wrong HTML containers, then *that* is the problem, not the shuffling itself.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah I noticed that Math.random isn't the best but I thought that it would be okay with something small I guess

Comment: @VLAZ https://codepen.io/shanice92/pen/pooPNOw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by following [Order two Arrays based on the same random sorting system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937278/order-two-arrays-based-on-the-same-random-sorting-system/51937452#51937452)

Just added an extra array to help the shuffle